# Проблема с методом Insert

Tags: c#

Есть метод, который вставляет пробелы перед прописными буквами.
Есть ошибка: в 1 вызове метода пробел ставится только 1 раз, даже если там есть много прописных букв.

```
BreakCamelCase("вывыВвывывы");
BreakCamelCase("вывыВвывDывы");
```

Ожидал получить в ответе:

вывы Ввывывы
вывы Ввыв Dывы

Получаю:
вывы Ввывывы
вывыВвыв Dывы

Код:

```
public static string BreakCamelCase(string str)
{
    string n = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.Length;i++)
    {
        if (Char.IsUpper(str[i]))
        {
            n = str.Insert(i, ' '.ToString());
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это происходит потому что на каждой итерации при срабатывании условия `if (Char.IsUpper(str[i]))` вы присваиваете переменной `n` **изначальное** значение переменной `str`, вставив в нужной позиции пробел. Тем самым вы просто затираете предыдущие изменения переменной `n`. Для решения проблемы вам нужно писать строку посимвольно, а не перезаписывать её заново при каждом срабатывании условия (в ответе ниже указан способ, не буду дублировать код). И да, при посимвольной работе со строками в цикле крайне желательно вместо `string` использовать `StringBuilder` - в силу неизменяемости строк на каждой итерации вашего цикла будет выделяться новая и притом всё бОльшая память под результирующую строку. `StringBuilder` же в свою очередь позволяет дописывать данные без создания строки заново

Answer (score 4):

Вы забываете что строки иммутабельны (неизменяемы).

Я бы переписал ваш код так:

```
public static string BreakCamelCase(string str)
{
    string n = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Char.IsUpper(str[i])) n += ' ';
        n += str[i];
    }
    return n;
}
```

Ну и в перспективе переход к `StringBuilder`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ошибку я понял, исправлю как-нибудь по своему

Comment: @Андрей дело тут всё же не в иммутабельности - автор просто перезаписывает всю строку целиком. Будь вместо `string` какой-то другой тип, в том числе мутабельный, код вида `a = b` привёл бы к аналогичным последствиям

Comment: @DreamChild, ну как сказать, если бы строки были мутабельными, они бы сохранили в себе вставленные ранее пробелы. Другой вопрос, что при отсутствии больших букв в строке вообще функция выдает null, ну и нужно учесть что при вставке длина строки меняется

Comment: @Андрей вне зависимости от мутабельности или её отсутствия в приведённом коде переменная перезаписывается целиком. На каждой следующей итерации строке присваивается новое значение, а старое затирается, а не модифицируется. К примеру StringBuilder мутабелен, но если в приведённом автором коде заменить тип переменной `n` со `string`  на `StringBuilder`, проблема останется так как на каждой итерации переменной `n` будет присвоено новое значение, тогда как нужно модифицировать старое, чтобы изменения, внесённые на предыдущих итерациях, сохранялись

Comment: @DreamChild, представим на секунду что `string` мутабельна, тогда при вставке в нее пробела он в ней останется и "перекочует" в n, в следующий раз мы добавим в строку еще пробел и он в ней также останется и также перекочует в n. Так что замечание про мутабельность считаю уместным, а дальнейшее обсуждение того чего нет - нет ) Со StringBuilder вы можете проверить сами и убедиться в своей ошибке. )

Comment: @DreamChild, простите, но убедить кого-то в своей правоте это так приятно :), поэтому вот: https://ideone.com/y6JbSO код авторский, заменил только `string` на `StringBuilder`, ну и добавил ++ для учета изменяющейся длины строки. Так что с очень большими "НО" код автора вполне рабочий при мутабельных строках.

Comment: @Андрей да, вы правы, я немного затупил, плюсую)